# Upgraded to 16.04 and kwallet now empty

Tags: 16.04, kwallet

I had a failure during an attempt to upgrade from 15.04 to 16.06 Kubuntu, so has to reinstall. I had backups to nothing permanently lost, by the new kwallet is not seeing any of my old wallet entries.

Is there any way to get the old wallet contents imported from the encrypted ./apps/kwallet/kdewallet.kwl into the new kwallet?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

Then I got a new wallet, but empty.

I had backups, so I tried to open my multiple wallets located under:
~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet/ (*.kwl and *.salt files)

KWallet asks for a password, but it cannot open the file. After searching and trying multiple solutions found on the Web, here is what did work for me:

- download an image of Kubuntu 14.04, and put it on a USB drive (using the `Startup Disk Creator` tool).
- reboot using this live Kubuntu
- when KDE desktop is up and running, I opened a terminal (`Konsole`)
- I copied my wallets files from my backup to `~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet`
- I launched kwallet daemon, otherwise I could not create/open wallets in kwallet: type `kwalletd` in the terminal
- Launched regular `KWallet` application: I can see my two wallets
- exported them as XML (somewhere accessible when rebooting)
- rebooted under my normal Kubuntu 16.04 desktop
- in the regular `KWallet` application, `Import XML` your XML exported files, into the (empty) existing wallet.
- delete the XML exports (Please note that these files are in clear text, and contain sensitive data. Think about deleting them securely if you think this might be needed)

Hope this helps!